# How do I get a signal from a QWiget to change get object?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Hello I have a QWidget and If I click on it, I want to get the object (the QWidget Element I clicked on) is there anyway to do that?

I already found some code but I only get the MouseClickEvent from

self.widget_34.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda event: self.myfunction(event)

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution offered by [@Cin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11655440/cin) is interesting, it has a serious problem: it cancels the mousePressEvent of the widget, so the widget loses the behavior it could have when the widget is pressed, for example the button no longer emits the clicked signal, other widget also They will have the same problem.

A less intrusive solution is to use eventFilter:

```py
import sys
import weakref
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class ClickListener(QtCore.QObject):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtWidgets.QWidget)

    def addWidget(self, widget, other_widget=None):
        if not hasattr(self, "_widgets"):
            self._widgets = {}
        widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self._widgets[widget] = widget if other_widget is None else other_widget
        weakref.ref(widget, self.removeWidget)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (
            obj in self._widgets
            and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress
        ):
            self.clicked.emit(self._widgets[obj])
        return super(ClickListener, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def removeWidget(self, widget):
        if hasattr(self, "_widgets"):
            if widget in self._widgets:
                del self._widgets[widget]


class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press Me")
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Stack Overflow")
        spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        te = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(label)
        lay.addWidget(spinBox)
        lay.addWidget(te)

        listener = ClickListener(self)
        listener.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        listener.addWidget(button)
        listener.addWidget(label)
        listener.addWidget(spinBox.lineEdit(), spinBox)
        listener.addWidget(te.viewport(), te)

    def onClicked(self, obj):
        print("Clicked, from", obj)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: But at this example I'm only able to click on labels, buttons, etc. and get there object. But I want to click on a specific Widget a get the Widget, so I can dye it. Like this example: https://imgur.com/jc7kog3

Comment: @D.Raphael If you have problems in implementing my solution then edit your question and provide a [mcve], so I will provide a code according to your code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will be a proper solution or not but I think, you can use the partial method of **functools** module. A collable object can be treated as a function for the purposes of this module. Here you can see my example,

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel
import functools

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(200,200,200,200)

        self.button = QPushButton('Button', self)
        self.button.move(50,50)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Label")
        self.label.move(100,100)

        self.items = [self.button, self.label]

        for i in self.items:
            i.mousePressEvent = functools.partial(self.getClickedItem, source_object=i)

        self.show()

    def getClickedItem(self, event, source_object=None):
        print("Clicked, from", source_object)
        #item text
        #print(source_object.text()) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```